# Terraform init puts an empty state file in my remove GCS backend but then creates a local state file

Tags: terraform, state, google-cloud-storage

I'm running terraform from a GCP compute instance to create projects using https://github.com/terraform-google-modules/terraform-google-project-factory

The definition seems correct--terraform creates a bare state file in the GCS bucket, but then after the apply, terraform has only created a local state file and doesn't update the remote backend statefile.

```
data "terraform_remote_state" "tfstate-gcp" {
  backend = "gcs"
    config = {
    bucket = "project-provisioning-state-5309"
    prefix = "project_${var.project_name}"
    }
```

}

As noted, running terraform init creates the bare backend state file in the correct bucket location:

```
{
  "version": 4,
  "terraform_version": "1.4.6",
  "serial": 1,
  "lineage": "ee20ff2d-f55d-aae0-7c4b-cbxyzxyzxead8",
  "outputs": {},
  "resources": [],
  "check_results": null
}
```

Running terraform apply, a terraform.tfstate file is created in the local directory, but the backend state file is not updated.

Any ideas what is going sideways?

Answer (score 1):

The configuration you've shown is using [the `terraform_remote_state` data source](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/state/remote-state-data) to retrieve the output values from another configuration's state.

To specify where to store the state for the *current* configuration, you will need to write a [backend configuration](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/settings/backends/configuration).

Comment: Thanks Martin, I'll check that out again and let you know. My previous attempt to add the backend to the config didn't work because I use a variable to create the bucket prefix.

Comment: I moved the backend config as noted in the documentation, however I got an error saying variables aren't allowed in the backend definition--which is why my predecessor used the data block I'm assuming.  ╷
│ Error: Variables not allowed
│ 
│   on main.tf line 38, in terraform:
│   38:     prefix = "state_file_${var.project_name}"
│ 
│ Variables may not be used here. Will keep looking at this problem.

Comment: I made the switch and removed the variable reference from the backend block. My hope was that I could use a variable simply and use definitions from terraform.tfvars which would make the automation simpler. Rather, I'll need to make that small change to the main.tf depending on the intended project context/folder. Thanks!